# Suggest facebook friends to download mobile app

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have written a mobile app using Phonegap and I have used...

```
FB.init({ appId: appid, nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });
FB.login(function(response){FB.api('/me', function(response) {});
```

... to sign in and ...

```
TDFriendSelector.init({debug: true});
  selector1 = TDFriendSelector.newInstance({
  callbackSubmit: function(selectedFriendIds) {});
selector1.showFriendSelector();
```

... to select a list of friends to invite using 'tdFriendsSelector'.

but I want to be able to send a message to my friends that have not registered in my app yet. I have a list of ids that are comma seperated but need to know how to message, post or invite them to download the app.

Any code hints, suggestions, ideas would be greatful, been stuck on this an entire day.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd suggest using the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) as this would do exactly what you need, but as you're building a PG app I suspect you'll have to iterate over the comma list of user IDs calling the Feed API directly each time via the [FB.api("/friend_id/feed")](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#feed) method. Note that you'll first have to get user permission (publish_stream) via. [FB authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) in order to post messages to their friend feeds. Unfortunately I don't have any PG-specific knowledge to help you with any of this.

Best of luck to you!